# Can we use Agora video using Unity AR Foundation with simultaniously using back and front camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

We tried using Agora video display in AR using AR Foundation, but noticed the following: in the AR Client we do see the video of a Standard client (so we see the video in AR floating around). However, we dont see the video stream from the AR Client in the Standard client. Could it be that the AR Client is using the back camera for the AR view and is not able to stream the front camera at the same time? If so, would this be possible too? If not, how could we make this work?

Answer (score 0):

your observation is correct. These are both hardware and software limitations.  Only few of the latest mobile devices support capture from both front and back cameras at the same time. You may want to google for these devices.  As for the software support, Agora Video SDK currently can handle one video stream output only.  Even you found a way to turn on both camera in Unity, the SDK won't be able to send them as separate streams.  In that case, you will need to combine the screens together as one stream to send.