# Agora video SDK for Unity is freezing the AR camera

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, video, augmented-reality, agora.io

I've been following Agora's tutorial for building an Augmented Reality video chat app https://www.agora.io/en/blog/video-chat-with-unity3d-the-arfoundation-version/. When I build it onto my iPhone the cube on which the video is playing on remains blank. Frustratingly, if I then remove this line of code`mRtcEngine.EnableLocalVideo(false);` the videos play but the AR camera freezes! Is there a way I can have both??

I'm using Unity version 2019.3.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can not use 2 cameras at once. See SO response, here, from a Agora.IO dev (or, seems to be a dev): [Can we use Agora video using Unity AR Foundation with simultaniously using back and front camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61540757/can-we-use-agora-video-using-unity-ar-foundation-with-simultaniously-using-back)